# How can I determine which Struts action is being invoked?

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-config

Please pardon me if my question sounds very basic. I am working on a project where they're using struts 1. My supervisor told me that the codes are very messed up. It seems to be that a combination of struts 1 framework and some self created framework are being used.

Is there a way to find out which method is being called when I click a button? I looked at the struts-config.xml file but it didn't help.

Is there a way to put a breakpoint automatically(dynamically) as soon as I click the button, so I know that this is the class being called?

Any help will be much appreciated.

struts-config file:

```
<action path="/adddispatches-fsav3-02-01" name="dispatchesForm" scope="request" 
type="com.us.web.struts.action.DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction" 
validate="false">
```

Methods in the class(because the class has over 5000 lines)
DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction.java

[image: DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction.java methods]

[image: DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction.java methods]

[image: DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction.java methods]

[image: DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction.java methods]

[image: DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction.java methods]

Comment: It might help if you post the relevant struts-config XML.

Comment: I have added a part of the struts-config file. I looked the at the class referred there but it seems that none of the method in that class is getting called.

Comment: Are you able to set a JavaScript break point in your browser to determine the URL that is being sent to the server when you click the button?

Comment: we're using IE7. I'm not sure if it can do that. If it can, I don't know how to do it. Although I can check and see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out what `Action` class your class, `com.us.web.struts.action.DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction` extends from.

If it extends `Action` directly, then the `execute(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` method is invoked. In your instance, it seems that your class doesn't extend any `DispatchAction` as there isn't any `parameter` attribute defined in your `<action />` tag in your `struts-config.xml` file.

Comment: my class--->A--->B--->C--->D--->org.apache.struts.action.Action. So basically what I mean to say is my class DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction has 5 ancestors. B and C have overridden execute(), I put a break point in both the execute(), but the break point is still not getting hit.

Comment: Then paste your code and see what we can do. I don't understand your "my class--->A--->B--->C--->D--->org.apache.struts.action.Action" format.

Comment: What I meant to say is that DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction extends class A. Class A extends B. B extends C. C extends D and D extends the struts Action class. I will try to paste the code here. It's just that the class is huge.

Comment: I have added the method signatures of all the methods in the class. Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: So, in essence class `D` implements the `execute` method. I suggest reading the code and see how it calls the relevant method in your `DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction` class. This typical example is of a design pattern called "Chain of Responsibility" pattern (if memory serves me correctly).

Answer (score 1):

It should be the "execute" method in the DispatchesNassSimpleSearchAction class. Though it is possible to have many method in a struts action if you use a custom dispatcher.

You're best bet is to set a break point in Java (or add logging) in the action methods in that class. The method signatures for actions look like this:

```
 public ActionForward someAction(ActionMapping mapping,
                               ActionForm aform,
                               HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response
```

Comment: I have a bunch of action methods in the class with that signature, but it looks like it's not calling any of the methods in that class.